# How can I add audit logs in different table?

Tags: php, laravel

I have been using the events and listeners, but only end up to update the **users** table.

I tried to change the handle in listener to, ***$event->log->description = 'something'***; but it says that

> Creating default object from empty value

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class LogSuccessfulLogin
{

    public function __construct()
    {
    //
    }

    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        $event->user->current_sign_in_at = Carbon::now();
        $event->user->save();
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is whenever a user has logged in, it should save a timestamp, description, action, to my **logs** table.

This is the table where I want to insert the logs.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/scCAh.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is happening because you are trying to assign a property to the  `$event->log` object, which does not exist.

However, to log the event, you could just use the query builder to insert a new record in the `logs` table.

For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; 

class LogSuccessfulLogin
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(Login $event)
    {
        $event->user->current_sign_in_at = Carbon::now();
        $event->user->save();

        $this->logEvent($event); 
    }

    private function logEvent(Login $event)
    {
        return DB::table('logs')
            ->insert([
                'user_id' => $event->user->id, 
                'description' => 'Some description', 
                'action' => 'login'
            ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for days already, and yet I did not realize that I can just use a query builder for this.

It works for me. Thank you!